# How to use Test:Unit on a ruby file without classes (only methods)

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

I have to write code for an homework and I wish to do TDD from the start.
The homework consists of one ruby file with methods in it, no class.

All examples I find on the Internet test against classes.  How could I test the following method?

**homework.rb**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def count_words(str)
  # SOME CODE HERE
end
```

There is an auto-grading system that take one ruby file with the methods defined for the homework as an input.  So, I have to write my tests in a separate file (test_homework.rb) or comment out my test before submitting (which I found counter productive...).

How will I test the count_words method using Test:Unit?

Comment: Your file is a class in itself, so cannot you just include Test::Unit to your file?

Comment: No I can't, there is an auto-grading system. I will have to remove my testing code before submitting the homework. I have to do my tests in a separate file.

Comment: Auto grading sound nifty, but in reality, it is a horrible idea. Tell that to your techer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
require File.join(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)), 'homework.rb')
require "test/unit"

class TestWordCounter < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_count_words
    assert_equal 3, count_words("one two three")
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that you can use *require_relative* instead of that messy path building if you are using >= ruby 1.9.2

Comment: @ireddick Thanks. In my case I'm stuck on Ruby 1.8.7 for the time being.